# Error: "this.geometry.morphTargets is undefined" ONLY with UTF8Loader?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, three.js

I got

> TypeError: this.geometry.morphTargets is undefined

in line 14558

with this UTF8Loader code:

```
   var loader = new THREE.UTF8Loader();
   loader.load("MD/ben-utf8.js", function (geometry) {
   callbackModel(geometry, 400, 0xffffff, 0, 0, 0);
   }, {scale: 0,offsetX: 0,offsetY: 0,offsetZ: 0});

   container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
   window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
   }
function callbackModel(geometry, s, color, x, y, z) {
   var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
       color: color,
       map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("MD/text.jpg"),
   }); 
   var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
   mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
   mesh.scale.set(s, s, s);
   scene.add(mesh);
}
```

But when i change loader to BinaryLoader like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
   loader.load("MD/ben-binary.js", function (geometry) {
   callbackModel(geometry, 400, 0xffffff, 0, 0, 0);
   }, {scale: 0,offsetX: 0,offsetY: 0,offsetZ: 0});

   container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
   window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
   }
function callbackModel(geometry, s, color, x, y, z) {
   var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
       color: color,
       map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("MD/text.jpg"),
   }); 
   var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
   mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
   mesh.scale.set(s, s, s);
   scene.add(mesh);
}
```

It's work.

I have try a lot and i see this problem alway happen when i try to add material.

### How to fix this? Is this a bug?

The material in webgl_loader_utf8.html file set like this:

```
object.traverse( function( node ) {

                    node.castShadow = true;
                    node.receiveShadow = true;

                    if ( node.material && ( node.material.name === "head" || node.material.name === "skinbody" ) ) {
                        node.material.wrapAround = true;
                        node.material.wrapRGB.set( 0.6, 0.2, 0.1 );
                       }

                } );
```

I haven't seen this material type before, can someone give me information about this?

Three.js R65.

Comment: Anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use UTF8Loader.... what is the purpose of creating a new mesh, because the geometry, material, mesh all are created inside the UTF8Loader and return as object.

```
loader.load("MD/ben-utf8.js", function (object) {
object.scale.set( 4,4,4 );
scene.add(object);

object.traverse( function( node ) {
    node.castShadow = true;
    node.receiveShadow = true;
    //texture wrapping on the material
    if ( node.material && ( node.material.name === "head" || node.material.name === "skinbody" ) ) {
        node.material.wrapAround = true;
        node.material.wrapRGB.set( 0.6, 0.2, 0.1 );
        }
   });
}
```

look inside the ../MD/ben-utf8.js file.. it has the jpg file details for texturing and the ben.utf8 file which will be loaded and readed by UTF8Loader...

Comment: Thanks user2089677 so much because get me understand how it work, so i have mod the UTF8Loader change mtl material loader to my material, thanks again, i will mark your question as right